# I am creating a copy of a Spreadsheet. How do I make a script to copy the users that can view/edit/own the file across aswell?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am creating a copy of a Spreadsheet. How do I make a script to copy the users that can view/edit/own the file across aswell?

Currently I cannot change the owner nor add editors or viewers that are as part of a googlegroup.

Thank you very much for your replies. GREATLY APPRECIATED.

I used this ...

```
var originalowner = originalSpreadsheet.getOwner();
var originaleditors = originalSpreadsheet.getEditors();
var originalviewers = originalSpreadsheet.getViewers();
//  Logger.log(originalowner);
//  Logger.log(originaleditors); 
//  Logger.log(originalviewers);
newSheet.addEditor(originaleditors);
```

`enter code here` newSheet.addViewer(originalviewers);

and get an error 
Invalid email: xxxxxxx@googlegroups.com, yyyyyyyyy@googlegroups.com

Answer (score 1):

If you read the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet?hl=fr-FR#addEditor%28String%29) you will see that the argument for `addEditor()` is a single email as a string.  You are trying to use an array of strings and the error message returned is quite explicit `Invalid email: xxxxxxx@googlegroups.com, yyyyyyyyy@googlegroups.com`

You should use a simple loop to add each viewer / editor one by one.

```
for(var n = 0 ; n<originaleditors.length ; ++n){
  newSheet.addEditor(originaleditors[n]);
}
```

and do the same for viewers...

**EDIT :** or, as mentioned in Fred's comment (good point ! ) use the `addEditors()` method (with an `s`) that takes an array of editors emails as argument.

*Note : as I said, (re)reading the documentation is always a good idea, that's true for me too ;-)*

Comment: There's `addEditors(emailAddresses)` and `addViewers(emailAddresses)` for multiple emails at once.

Comment: Oooops... didn't pay attention.. I should read the documentation :-)    thanks... that said, both solutions will work, I'll edit my answer.